# InvalidProgramException: Method GameSystems.BonusWordsSystem.Model.BonusWordsDictionary:.cctor () is too complex

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

[image: The dictionary]

So, basically i have this huge dictionary i'm using to validate a words puzzle, it was working fine when the dictionary was small (it also used to be an array) but as the size grew i decided to make it a dictionary for faster searches, however this caused the code to die and start throwing the error :

```
InvalidProgramException: Method GameSystems.BonusWordsSystem.Model.BonusWordsDictionary:.cctor () is too complex.
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'GameSystems.BonusWordsSystem.Model.BonusWordsDictionary' threw an exception.
Helpers.CodeBenchmarker.SearchTest (System.Action`1[T] func, System.String name) (at
```

I've already googled for answers and the solutions i found were "go back to using an array" or "make it less complex" to which my question is ... how !?. Any hints on how to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: seems that the problem is inside the constructor, is too big (complex). Did you think in holding your dictionary in a 'external' JSON file and read/parse it in the constructor?

Comment: Looks like it is just way too many items in your dictionary ... is this an entire actual Dictionary?

Comment: @derHugo Yeah it is basically an actual dictionary